# Combinatorial Math Formula / Algo?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm doing some data analysis within excel and i'm looking for a formula / systematic approach for solving an equation programmatically. When I looked at the analysis, it's similar to some lotto combinatorial math.

Q. Is there a formula that could calculate all possible combinations (sets) of say 6 numbers that would equal a total (sum)? Using a lotto example, find all combinations of 6 numbers (from 49) that equal X.

Example, the two sets below both equal 100. However there are many more combinations of possible numbers within the range from 1-49 that also would equal 100.

Set 1 10 14 15 17 18 26 = 100 Set 2 4 10 14 15 26 31 = 100 Set 3... Set 4... List all other possible combinations that equal sum of 100.

Thinking formula would be need 3 variables: 1. Size of set (combination) e.g., 6 2. Upper bound Number of Range to choose from e.g., 49 3. Sum total solving for e.g. 100

"Formula" ideally would take - any number for size of set (6, 8 etc.) - variable for number of upper bounds of range (49, 59 etc) - Sum total solving for (100, 500 etc.) Output: (excel?) would display all possible combinations (sets) that would equal Sum Total

Assumption is same as Lotto where number cannot be re-used. i.e., only one 5, only one 22 or only one 49.

Would appreciate greatly any thoughts or comments on how to achieve this. I'm currently trying to facilitate via MS Excel.

Thanks all!

Comment: There are several Questions, both here and at StackOverflow, about formulas that enumerate the combinations of $m$ things taken $k$ at a time.  The difficulty is that the count of such combinations $\binom{m}{k}$ can be to large for MS Excel to handle.  Note that the specific constraint that the sum of the combination equal $X$ can be handled as an integer programming problem.  Again there are previous Questions here about counting or listing such solutions.  I'll try to find you such links.

Comment: You are looking for the partitions of $100$ into $6$ unequal parts no greater than $49$.  Do you want to compute how many there are or list them all?  There will be a lot of them.  To list them I would just write a program with five loops, looping over the five smaller numbers and recording all the cases where the sixth number is in range.  I think you will find some millions of cases.

Comment: Good afternoon, thank you for your response.  My question wasn't constrained or specific to 49 (it could be 39, 40 etc.).  I'm just looking at trying to do this in code as you suggested but thought I would check here.  I will try to do this in some python code.  Thanks again for your response.